# Jinja template inherited but not able to modify it on other files

Tags: html, django, jinja2

This is my base.html:

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <style>/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
        .topnav {
          background-color: rgb(10, 113, 145);
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
        .topnav a {
          float: left;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
        }
        
        /* Change the color of links on hover */
        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
        
        /* Add a color to the active/current link */
        .topnav a.active {
          background-color: #04AA6D;
          color: white;
        }
        *{
          color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="/">Home Page</a>
        <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Projects.html:

```
{% extends "important/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <title>Projects</title>
    <h1>Projects</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Iam not able to see anything on my projects pae even I did everything correctly Is there anything that I can change in this to make it work? please help me with this. Iam a self taught programmer and this is really stopping me from enhancing my skills. So, please help me.

Comment: Your `base.html` has no `{% block content %}`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.
.
.
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="/">Home Page</a>
        <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>

</body>
```

You have not created a block template tag in the `base.html`
Create like this

```
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="/">Home Page</a>
        <a href="/projects">Projects</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
```

In simple terms :

If `base.html` has

```
<body>
  <div class="nav-bar">
      ---whatever---
  </div>
  {% block content %}
     <div class="base"></div>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

and in your `project.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
   {% block content %}
      <h1>Projects</h1>
   {% endblock %}
```

Then result is

```
<body>
  <div class="nav-bar">
      ---whatever---
  </div>
  {% block content %}
     <h1>Projects</h1>
  {% endblock %}
</body>
```

Focus on the `block part`

So you need a block template tag in your `base.html` so that you can replace contents in your project.html

Comment: Why you reverted the accepted status ? Any bugs ?

Comment: Made the changes properly ? sure ? Any error showing up ? You can update your post with the changes you made. will see if i can help

Comment: Yes I will do it now

Comment: When you now ask me to do changes please send all the code sothat the placewhere I gotta add the code will not be changed

Comment: `{% extends "important/base.html" %}` here `base.html` is in the same folder as of `project.html` ? If yes then it should be `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Comment: Ok make that `{% extends "base.html" %}`

Comment: `Piece of advice` : `<title>Projects</title>` this can't be in body. It should be in `head` tag + consider putting your css in seperate file or `head` tag , putting it  in body is a bad practice.  Anyway glad it worked!